# Flex 3 reads browser http proxy setting

Tags: apache-flex, http, browser, actionscript, proxy

Is there a way to know the proxy setting of web browser under Flex 3, namely actionscript 3?

We use socket library to connect remote HTTP server.  It is nice to read web proxy setting to connect to HTTP proxy instead of directly to HTTP server.

Answer (score 1):

The Socket API in Flash Player doesn't use the browser proxy settings.  If you use the other networking APIs in Flash Player (URLLoader, NetConnection, etc) then they use the browser networking APIs internally so the proxy settings are preserved.